# No such table: solutions_account when I create another superuser

Tags: django, django-models

Long story short, I messed up my migrations and ended up deleting them, but now when I create a superuser the compiler gives me an error saying that I have no table.  What can I do to start from a completely clean slate?

**Edit 1**
Now I get a traceback exception saying this:

```
python3 manage.py createsuperuser
<django.forms.models.ModelMultipleChoiceField object at 0x10b44ea10>
what is going on
Email: email@gmail.com
Username: whatter
Password: 
Password (again): 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/macbook/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/macbook/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/macbook/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/macbook/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 61, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/macbook/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/macbook/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 156, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
TypeError: create_superuser() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'first_name' and 'last_name'
```

This is my custom user model called Account:

```
class MyAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, first_name, last_name, email, password = None):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("Users must have a username")
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have an email")

        user = self.model(
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            username = username,
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using = self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, first_name, last_name, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            username = username,
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            password = password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using = self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, username, first_name, last_name, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            username = username,
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            first_name = first_name,
            last_name = last_name,
            password = password,
        )
        user.is_admin = False
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = False
        user.save(using = self._db)
        return user

class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name = 'email', max_length = 250, unique = True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 250, unique = True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = 'date joined', auto_now_add = True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = 'last login', auto_now_add = True)

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username',]

    #app_label = 'Account'

    objects = MyAccountManager()

    #class Meta:
        #abstract = True
        #app_label = 'Account'
        #abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj = None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    def get_url(self):
        return reverse('profile', args = [self.username])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this error :-

> TypeError: create_superuser() missing 2 required positional arguments:
>   'first_name' and 'last_name'

is because you have not entered first_name and last_name in console, but at the same time it does not prompt for you to enter these details, if you add

```
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'first_name', 'last_name']
```

it will prompt like this :

> - Email: admin@root.com
> - First name: Admin
> - Last name: Root
> - Phone: 9182374812
> - Password: Password (again):

Good luck and just one more thing please don't take `auto_now_add` like this in `DateTimeField`:

```
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = 'date joined', auto_now_add = True)
last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name = 'last login', auto_now_add = True)
```

Instead use:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
```

and then:

```
date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
last_login = models.DateTimeField(_('last login'), default=timezone.now)
```

Comment: Please describe!

Comment: Email: email@gmail.com
Username: whatter
Password: 
Password (again):
here there is no option to enter first_name and last_name that is why i advised to add them to required fields so that when you type python manage.py createsuperuser they will show up

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are beginner and may be using a SQLite database,
just delete the sqlite file in you project folder, then run

`python manage.py makemigrations`

`python manage.py migrate`

to start from completely clean slate.

======================================

Prototype of your function is probably wrong

```py
def create_superuser(self, username, first_name, last_name, email, password):
```

this function will not work without `first_name` and `last_name`, but those are not required or taken input when you run `createsuperuser`, either set a default function parameter for them, or override CLI to ask  `first_name`, `last_name` as user input.

have a look at [this code at github](https://github.com/django/django/blob/9762617a03f2bff93384604799572e4fdf4b00b4/django/contrib/auth/models.py#L148) if you can change the create_superuser function this will work out for sure.

Comment: I just figured that part out, thank you.  Now I get another error when I make a superuser that says: create_superuser() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'first_name' and 'last_name'.  Would you be willing to chat?

Comment: are you using this command `python manage.py createsuperuser`?

Comment: Yes.  I made sure that USERNAME_FIELD and REQUIRED_FIELDS are all correct. this has worked before.

Comment: Can you update your question with what is in your console right now.

Comment: Done.  Can you take a look at my stacktrace?